# Python: How to split a string with csv reader that has optional quotes

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to split a comma seperated string where field **may** or
**may not** have quotes around them.

Is there a way to define quotes to be **optional**?

The code below only works with quoted fields.
I'm using python 2.7.11

```
import csv

temp = '"HELLO,WORLD",HELLO WORLD,END OF THE WORLD'

for i in csv.reader(temp):
    print('#next#')
    print(i)
```

The output is

```
#next       
['HELLO,WORLD']    
#next#    
['', '']    
#next#    
['H'] 
#next#     
['E']    
...
```

Expected out is

```
#next       
['HELLO,WORLD']    
#next       
['HELLO WORLD']    
#next       
['END OF THE WORLD']
```

Comment: Just pass `[temp]` to `csv.reader` call

Comment: Thanks. That was too easy!
If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) documentation:

```
csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
    Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile.
csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and
returns a string each time its next() method is called ..
```

So, you need to pass a list of strings to your `csv.reader` call
in order to get the correct output.

```
temp = ['"HELLO,WORLD",HELLO WORLD,END OF THE WORLD']
```